# PHP: $myObject = new ClassName(); vs newClassName;

Tags: php, class, variables, parameters, arguments

So, I understand that sometimes people use parens and sometimes they don't when declaring an instance of a class as an object.

If I declare a class without arguments and then extend it to have arguments, will the initial class need to have had parens?

Furthermore, can I have a class with brackets and no specific parameter or reference variable declaration like this:

$myObject = clone ClassName();

And then use parameters for the class....

class User($param, $param2)

Or do classes ever even use parameters?  I'm not really sure because there isn't an example of a class that takes parameters in my book....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those parameters, eg

```
$myObject = new ClassAwesome($param1, $param2);
```

dont correspond to the class declaration, they relate to the constructor. An example:

```
//this is how you declare a class, there will not be a parenthesis here
class ClassAwesome {

    //here is where the parameters are used when you instantiate a class
    public function __construct($param1, $param2) {
        //init code goes here
    }
}
```

So basically the reason you dont see a class declaration with parameters is because they dont exist, the class constructor is where the parameters go.

Answer (score 10):

First, I assume you mean `new` instead of `clone`. PHP does not require that you use parenthesis when creating a class.

```
class Foo { }

$foo = new Foo;
$foo = new Foo();
```

Both are valid.

Any arguments you send are passed to the `__construct` function. That function (if it exists) is automatically called when you create the object.

```
class Foo
{
  public function __construct($n)
  {
     echo "Hello, $n\n";
  }
}

$foo = new Foo("World!");
```

That will output:

```
Hello, World!
```

If the constructor takes arguments, then it is an error (warning) if you don't send any.

Note that `__construct` doesn't need to have parameters. It is valid to have a constructor that simply does something without any parameters.

Comment: I'm just wondering why sometimes instances of classes are called with parameters, though.  I guess if the constructor has parameters, you can call the object with them....

Comment: If the constructor has non-optional parameters, then you MUST pass them when you create the object.

Comment: @Matthew what are the difference between `$foo = new Foo;` and 
`$foo = new Foo();` except the passing arguments to the constructor?